# Update joined table from one row to another

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert

I have joined a table

```
SELECT t1.akademik, t1.entity_id, t2.akademik AS akademik_doboru, t2.uid_author 
FROM zakwalifikowani1 t1 
JOIN dobor2 t2 
ON t1.entity_id = t2.uid_author
```

My joined table

```
    akademik |  entity_id | akademik_doboru |   uid_author |
    Feniks   |     129    |                 |     129      |
```

How can I copy value **akademik** from this joined table into table dobor2

I tried something like this:

```
$sql=("SELECT t1.akademik, t1.entity_id, t2.akademik AS akademik_doboru, t2.uid_author 

FROM zakwalifikowani1 t1 JOIN dobor2 t2 ON t1.entity_id = t2.uid_author");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $a=$row['akademik'];
        $b=$row['entity_id'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO dobor2 ('akademik') VALUES ('$a') WHERE uid_author = '$b'  ");
    }
```

Nothing happend if I use this code :(

Comment: it should be `update dobor2 set akademik = '$a' WHERE uid_author = '$b'`

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work :( It is so weird for me :/

Comment: I get such error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single query. Try this (did not test):

```
UPDATE dobor2 t2 
    JOIN zakwalifikowani1 t1 ON t1.entity_id = t2.uid_author 
SET t2.akademik = t1.akademik
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `update` not an `insert`.  You *update* columns in an individual row.  You *insert* new rows into the table.  I think this is what you are looking for:

```
update dobor2 d2 join
       zakwalifikowani1 z
       on z.entity_id = d2.uid_author
    set d2.akademik = z.akademik;
```